# Showing that, at an elliptic point, a surface lies on one side of the tangent plane.

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

Let $p\in S$ be an elliptic point of a surface $S$. I want to show that there exists a neighbourhhod $V$ of $p$ in $S$ such that all points in $V$ belong to the same side of the tangent plane $T_p(S)$. The book I'm reading (Do Carmo), proceeds as follows:

Let $\mathbf{x}$ be a parametrization at $p$, with $\mathbf{x}(0,0)=p$. We consider the distance function:

$$d(u,v)=\langle \mathbf{x}(u,v)-p,N(p) \rangle$$

Applying Taylor's Formula we obtain:

$$\mathbf{x}(u,v)=\mathbf{x}(0,0)+\mathbf{x}_u u +\mathbf{x}_v v+\frac{1}{2}(\mathbf{x}_{uu}u^2+2\mathbf{x}_{uv} uv + \mathbf{x}_{vv}v^2)+\overline{R}$$

where all derivatives are evaluated at $(0,0)$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{(u,v)\to (0,0)}\frac{\overline{R}(u,v)}{u^2+v^2}=0$. Rearranging the terms:

$$d(u,v)=\frac{1}{2}II_p(w)+R(u,v)$$

where $II_p(\cdot)$ is the ssecond fundamental form at $p$, $w=u\mathbf{x}_u+v\mathbf{x}_v$ and $R(u,v)=\langle \overline{R}(u,v),N(p)\rangle$.

The author claims that $\lim_{w\to \mathbf{0}}\frac{R}{|w|^2}=0$.

**My question is** Why is this? The norm $|w|$ is given by the first fundamental form $|w|^2=I_p(w)=Eu^2+2Fuv+Gv^2$, with $EG-F^2>0$. Hence:

$$\frac{\overline{R}}{|w|^2}=\frac{u^2+v^2}{Eu^2+2Fuv+Gv^2}\frac{\overline{R}}{u^2+v^2}$$

If I could show that the quotient $$\frac{u^2+v^2}{Eu^2+2Fuv+Gv^2}$$ is bounded in a neighbourhood of $(0,0)$, then I would be done, but I don't see why this should be the case.

Any ideas? (or alternative proofs of the initial claim?).

Comment: Because the first fundamental form is everywhere positive definite, so (by continuity) near $(0,0)$ the denominator is bounded below by $c(u^2+v^2)$ for some $c>0$.

Comment: @TedShifrin I'm sorry, I don't see how that follows, could you please be a bit more specific? Thank you very much!

Comment: By the Spectral Theorem, you can orthogonally diagonalize the symmetric matrix $A = \begin{bmatrix} E & F \\ F & G\end{bmatrix}$, and you can check that $A\mathbf x\cdot\mathbf x \ge c\|\mathbf x\|^2$, where $c$ is the smaller eigenvalue of $A$ (which is necessarily positive by positive definiteness).

Comment: @TedShifrin Ah, of course! Thank you so much! If you wan't to add your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the Spectral Theorem, you can orthogonally diagonalize the first fundamental form matrix $A=\begin{bmatrix} E&F\\F&G\end{bmatrix}$, and from this it follows that $A\mathbf x\cdot\mathbf x \ge c\|\mathbf x\|^2$, where $c$ is the smaller eigenvalue of $A$. Since the first fundamental form is everywhere positive definite and varies continuously on the surface, it is straightforward to check that your denominator is (on any compact set, hence locally in your surface) bounded below by $c(u^2+v^2)$ for some $c>0$.